# Almost everywhere convergence of subsequence in Bochner space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, bochner-spaces

Does the familiar theorem that convergence in $L^p$ implies almost everywhere convergence along a subsequence also hold in Bochner spaces?

I.e., for a Banach space $B$ does $f_n\to f$ in $L^p(\Omega;B)$ imply the existence of a subsequence such that $f_{n_k}(\omega)\to f(\omega)$ in $B$ for almost every $\omega$?

Comment: $\|f_n-f\| \to 0$ in $L^{p}$ so there is  a subsqeeunce with $\|f_{n_k}-f\| \to 0$ a.e..

Comment: That was obvious, why didn't I see that? Too stuck up in more complicated stuff. Thanks.